# Getting local.ERROR: Route [login] not defined when uploading file from ionic to laravel using fileTransfer plugin

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, file-upload

I'am using Rest api to upload file from ionic to laravel , First i prepare the api in laravel and the function in controller it work's fine in laravel , second in ionic app i'am using file , filepath , filetransfert as you see in the code bellow . but when i test i get local.ERROR: Route [login] not defined
in laravel.log.
this my code in laravel controller

```
  public function complaintsfile(Request $request){
        $reclamation = Reclamation::latest('updated_at')->first();
        $file = new Filee;
        if(!$request->hasFile('file')){
        return response()->json([
            "action"=>"File empty"
        ]);
        }
        else{
            $this->validate($request,[
             'file' => 'required|mimes:doc,png,jpg,docx,txt,pdf|max:2048'
              ]);
        $extention = time().'.'.$request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName ="complain".'.'.$extention;
        $request->file->move(public_path('upload'), $fileName);
        $file->file= $fileName;
        $file->rec_id=$reclamation->id;
        $file->save();
        }
    }
```

Also this my code in ionic

```
export class FillPage {

  myRec = {
    type:'' ,
    project:'' ,
    description:'',
 
   }
   myFile={
     file:''
   }
   mood:any;
   project:any;
   uploadText:any;
   downloadText:any;
   fileTransfer:FileTransferObject;
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public complaint: ComplaintProvider
     ,public transfer:FileTransfer,public file:File,public filePath:FilePath,public fileChooser:FileChooser) {
     this.complaint.Type().then((data)=>{
    //   console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
         this.mood=data["type"];
        })
        this.complaint.Project().then((data)=>{
      //   console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
           this.project=data["projects"];
          })
          this.uploadText="";
          this.downloadText="";
   }
 
   uploadFile(){
    this.fileChooser.open().then((uri)=>{
         this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri).then((nativepath)=>{
           this.fileTransfer =this.transfer.create();
           let options:FileUploadOptions={
             fileKey:"pdf",
             fileName:"file.pdf",
             chunkedMode:false,
             headers:{},
             mimeType:'pdf'
           }
           this.uploadText ="uploading .....";
           this.fileTransfer.upload(nativepath,'http://192.168.1.14:8000/api/complainfile',options).then((data)=>{
             alert("transfer done="+JSON.stringify(data));
             this.uploadText="";
 
           },(err)=>{
             this.uploadText=""
           })
         },(err)=>{
           alert(JSON.stringify(err))
         })
    },(err)=>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
   })
   }
   AbortUplaod(){
     this.fileTransfer.abort();
     alert("upload cancel.");
   }
```

api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::group([

//  'middleware' => 'api',
 // 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
 'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

  Route::post('login', 'API\AuthenController@login');
  Route::post('logout', 'API\AuthenController@logout');
  Route::post('refresh', 'AuthenController@refresh');
  Route::post('me', 'AuthenController@me');
  Route::get('/me','API\AuthenController@me');
});  

Route::get('/notif','API\ProjetController@notifications');
Route::get('/notification','API\ProjetController@notif');
Route::get('/me','API\AuthenController@guard');
Route::post('/login','API\AuthenController@login');
Route::post('/userauth','API\AuthenController@userauth');
Route::post('/markAsRead','API\ProjetController@MarkUnread') ;  
   
Route::apiResource('client' ,'API\UserController@dashbord');
Route::get('membrep','API\UserController@Membreprojet');
Route::get('/chef', 'API\UserController@chef');
Route::post('/ajouterChefDeProjet','API\UserController@ajouterChefDeProjet');
Route::post('user-login' ,'API\UserController@login');
Route::apiResource('membre','API\UserController');
Route::post('updateuserconnecte','API\UserController@updateuserconnecté');
Route::get('/chef','API\UserController@chefprojet');
Route::get('/chefwP','API\UserController@chefprojetwP');
Route::get('userprofile/{id}','API\UserController@userprofile');

//UserProjet
Route::apiResource('/userprojet' ,'API\UserProjetController');
Route::get('/membreid/{id}','API\UserProjetController@show');
Route::get('/projetsuser','API\UserProjetController@projetuser');
Route::post('/chefdeprojet','API\UserProjetController@storeChef');
Route::post('/chefdeprojetparchef','API\UserProjetController@storeChefparchef');

//Client
//Route::post('/api/clientpname','API\UserController@updatename');
Route::get('nameprojet' ,'API\UserController@nomdeprojet');
Route::get('clientp','API\UserController@clientprojet');
Route::post('/ajouterClient','API\UserController@ajouterClient');
Route::get('/afficheclient', 'API\UserController@client');
//Projet
Route::get('/getProjects', 'API\ProjetController@getProjects');
Route::apiResource('projet' ,'API\ProjetController');
Route::post('/role' ,'API\ProjetController@role');
Route::get('/role','API\ProjetController@getrole');
Route::get('/projetadmin','API\ProjetController@adminp');
Route::get('/getProjectsUserConnecte', 'API\ProjetController@getProjectsUserConnecte');

//Commentaire
Route::post('/comments/{key}', 'API\CommentController@store');
Route::get('/comments', 'API\CommentController@show');
Route::post('/commentsreponse/{key}', 'API\CommentController@storereply');
Route::post('/commentsreponset/{key}', 'API\CommentController@storereplyt');
Route::get('/commentreply', 'API\CommentController@showreply');
Route::post('/commentst/{key}', 'API\CommentController@storet');
Route::get('/commentst', 'API\CommentController@showt');

//calendar
Route::apiResource('/calendar', 'API\CalenderController');

//gantt

Route::resource('/task', 'API\TaskController');
Route::post('/task/{key}','API\TaskController@store');
Route::put('task/{id}','API\TaskController@update');
Route::delete('task/{id}','API\TaskController@destroy');

Route::post('link','API\LinkController@store');
Route::put('link/{id}','API\LinkController@update');
Route::delete('link/{id}','API\LinkController@destroy');
//Route::re}source('link', 'API\LinkController');
Route::get('/tasks','API\TaskController@getTask');
Route::get('/tasksdetail','API\TaskController@getTaskt');
//Task
Route::post('/taskassign/{id}/{membre}','API\TaskController@assign');
Route::get('/userTask','API\TaskController@user');
Route::get('/hasparent','API\TaskController@hasparent');
Route::get('membret/{id}','API\UserProjetController@showt');
Route::get('warn','API\TaskController@warning');
Route::get('membretask','API\TaskController@showmembre');

//reclamation
Route::resource('reclamation','API\ReclamationController');
Route::get('/complain','API\ReclamationController@complaints');
Route::post('/complainfile','API\ReclamationController@complaintsfile');
Route::post('/complainfileionic','API\ReclamationController@complaintsfileionic'); 
Route::get('/filesComplain/{id}','API\FileController@complaintsfile');
Route::get('/projetRec','API\ReclamationController@projets');
Route::post('/reclamationassign/{id}/{membre}','API\ReclamationController@assign');
Route::post('/type' ,'API\ReclamationController@type');
Route::get('/type','API\ReclamationController@gettype');
Route::post('/reclamationTerm/{id}','API\ReclamationController@terminerReclamation');
Route::post('/reclamationAlert/{id}','API\ReclamationController@alertReclamation');
Route::get('/reclamationmobile','API\ReclamationController@reclamationmobile');
//profil
Route::put('profile', 'API\UserController@updateProfile');
Route::get('membrechef','API\UserController@Membrechefprojet');
//File
Route::get('/file/{id}','API\FileController@files');
Route::post('formSubmit/{id}','API\FileController@formSubmit');
Route::get('/filet/{id}','API\FileController@filest');
Route::post('formSubmitt/{id}','API\FileController@formSubmitt');
Route::post('formSubmitR','API\FileController@formSubmitR');
//stata
Route::get('/Nprojects','API\StatController@Nprojects');
Route::get('/Nclients','API\StatController@Nclients');
Route::get('/Nusers','API\StatController@Nusers');
Route::get('/Nleaders','API\StatController@Nleaders');
Route::get('/stats','API\StatController@stats');
Route::get('/Uprojects','API\StatController@Uprojects');
Route::get('/Ustats','API\StatController@Ustats');
Route::get('/Utasks','API\StatController@Utasks');
Route::get('/Cprojets','API\StatController@Cprojets');
Route::get('/Cprojet','API\StatController@projetsclient');
Route::get('/Ucomplaint','API\StatController@complaints'); 
Route::get('/Nprojectsc','API\StatController@NprojectsC');
Route::get('/NcomplaintsC','API\StatController@NcomplaintsC');
//});

Route::get('/data/{id}', 'API\GanttController@get');

Route::get('/data', 'GanttController@get');

Route::get('/verifcomplaint' ,'API\ReclamationController@verifcomplaint');
```

Anyone know this problem please !

Comment: Post your routes file please.

Comment: @KurtFriars i edit the post , now you can see api.php the routes file

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is probably because you are not authorized
you need to add to header request in iconic the `Bearer {token}`
and add
 `Accept: application/json`